# Mean value between dates based on dates in another dataset using R

Tags: r

I have two data frames "Conc" and "Flow".

Flow has a value for every day for a set period, whereas Conc only has a value on certain days over the period of the period.

What I want to be able to do is calculate the mean Flow values for each period in between the Conc values using r.

The following code will generate two example data frames to illustrate the kind of datasets I am working with:

```
Conc <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2012/01/13", "2012/02/16", "2012/05/02", "2012/07/28",
        "2012/11/10")), Conc = c(0.88, 0.55, 0.34, 0.21, 0.98))
Flow <- data.frame(Date = c(seq(as.Date("2012/01/01"), by = "day", length.out = 365)), 
        Flow = c(sample(seq(from = 0.01, to = 5, by = 0.1), size = 365, replace = TRUE)))
```

The output data frame would ideally be something like:

```
Period    Mean_Flow
1         2.01
2         1.41
3         3.81
4         0.31
```

I appreciate the variable time between Conc days makes this tricky. At present the best I have been to come up with is to manually do this in excel but I would really like to find an R solution to save myself having to do this for about 10 different dataset that I have.

Thank you.

Comment: You should probably add `as.Date` to `Conc` too

Comment: Also, don't you have only 4 periods here?

Comment: Thanks for spotting those errors David, I have now amended my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a possible approach using `data.table` package `foverlaps` function:

Create time intervals in both data sets

```
library(data.table)
Conc <- setDT(Conc)[, `:=`(start = Date, end = c(Date[2:(.N - 1)] - 1, Date[.N], NA))][-.N]
Flow <- setDT(Flow)[, `:=`(start = Date, end = Date)]
```

Key the `Flow` data set in order to use `foverlaps` function and run the function

```
setkey(Flow, start, end)
overlaps <- foverlaps(Conc, Flow, type = "any", which = TRUE)
```

Create indexes of the overlaps within the `Flow` data set and compute the mean by those indexes

```
Flow[overlaps$yid, Period := overlaps$xid]
na.omit(Flow[, list(Mean_Flow = mean(Flow)), by = Period])
#    Period Mean_Flow
# 1:      1  2.189412
# 2:      2  2.263947
# 3:      3  2.762874
# 4:      4  2.349048
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this David. Once again Data.Table provides the answer I was looking for! This works very well. J

Answer (score 0):

The following uses a loop going along all available dates in Conc$Date. 
Conc$Date is for convenience put in vector A. The variable p signifies the values that should be taken into account. The loop stops with a NaN as the loop surpasses the last given date.

```
A <- Conc$Date

for(i in 1:length(A))
{p <- which(Flow$Date>A[i] & Flow$Date<A[i+1])
M<-mean(Flow$Flow[p])
print(M)}
```